# Select column based on column name stored in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get a cell value from another table (UserTable) for which the column of the cell is specified in the original table (DataTable). The cell value is going to be used to calculate a score which will then determine the ordering of the query results.

```
UserTable:
+--------+------+------+------+
| userid | c1   | c2   | c3   |
+--------+------+------+------+
|    id1 |    0 |    1 |    1 |
|    id2 |    0 |    0 |    1 |
|    id3 |    1 |    0 |    0 |
|    id4 |    1 |    1 |    0 |
+--------+------+------+------+

DataTable:
+--------+------+------+------+
| id     | ColA | ColB | ColC |
+--------+------+------+------+
|      1 | A    | B    | c1   |
|      2 | D    | E    | c3   |
|      3 | G    | H    | c2   |
|      4 | J    | K    | c3   |
+--------+------+------+------+
```

My current, not working, query is:

```
SELECT *, 
       (SELECT DataTable.ColC 
        FROM UserTable 
        WHERE UserTable.userid = 'some_user_id') AS score 
FROM DataTable 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

But this doesn't select the appropriate column in UserTable and instead returns the string value contained in ColC.

The expected output:
If 'some_user_id' was set to 'id2' for example. The the expected output would be:

```
+--------+------+------+------+------+
| id     | ColA | ColB | ColC | score|
+--------+------+------+------+------+
|      2 | D    | E    | c3   |  1   |
|      4 | J    | K    | c3   |  1   |
|      1 | A    | B    | c1   |  0   |
|      3 | G    | H    | c2   |  0   |
+--------+------+------+------+------+
```

where the score column is simply the lookup of the value from the UserTable.

Is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: I have just updated it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this dynamically. But you can build a CASE statement that maps column names to columns:

```
SELECT DataTable.*, (
    SELECT CASE DataTable.ColC
        WHEN 'c1' THEN UserTable.c1
        WHEN 'c2' THEN UserTable.c3
        WHEN 'c3' THEN UserTable.c3
    END
    FROM UserTable
    WHERE UserTable.userid = 'id2'
) AS score
FROM DataTable
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, I appreciate it! Although it is slightly annoying it cannot be done dynamically as my columns changes over time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @expr nvarchar(max);  
Declare @value nvarchar(max);   
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR  
FOR Select colC from dbo.DataTable;

OPEN db_cursor;  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @value;  
Set @expr = 'Select ' + @value;  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
       Set @expr += ',' + @value  
       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @value;  
END;  
CLOSE db_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;  

EXEC (@expr + ' from dbo.UserTable')
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. Have you tested this code / what version of mysql are you using? On 5.6 the syntax doesn't checkout. For example should the first two Declare statements not instead be SET statements?

Answer (score 0):

I like to express this by unpivoting the user table:

```
select dt.*, uts.score
from datatable dt left join
     ((select ut.userid, 'c1' as which, c1 as score
       from usertable ut
      ) union all
      (select ut.userid, 'c2' as which, c2 as score
       from usertable ut
      ) union all
      (select ut.userid, 'c3' as which, c3 as score
       from usertable ut
      ) 
     ) uts
     on dt.colc = uts.which 
where uts.userid = ?;
```

The reason I prefer this approach is because the subquery suggests the table that you really need.  You should not be storing the different score values in columns.  You should have a `userScores` table with one row per user and per score.

Comment: You make a good point. I think I am going to make a table for each userid, with a row for each column (c1, c2, c3) along with the corresponding score. For my application there are thousands of these columns named c1..cN